# Forcing std::vector overload instead of int overload on list with one element

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, overloading, initializer-list

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void f(std::vector<int> v) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
void f(int n) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    f({42}); // the int overload is being picked up
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c739f84d8926bea7)

I was a bit surprised to realize that in this case the int overload is being picked up, i.e. the output of the program is:

> void f(int)

with the warning

> warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init] f({42});

Of course this happens only when I pass a 1-element list as an argument, otherwise the `std::vector` overload is being picked up.

**Why is `{42}` treated like a scalar and not like a init-list? Is there any way of forcing the compiler to pick the `std::vector` overload (without explicitly constructing `std::vector<int>{42}`) even on 1-element lists?**

PS: The `std::vector` has an init-list constructor

```
vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

see (7) from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: You might add overload `void f(std::initializer_list)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 But `vector` has an `initializer_list` ctor, why isn't it being picked up? AFAIK, the init list ctors trump everything else. I think there's a rule that says `{42}` is an int and not an init-list (of course holds for numbers different from 42 :) )

Comment: I'd suggest designing the class so that single-int argument behaves the same as vector of one int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Braced initializer has no type, we can't say `{42}` is an `int` or `std::initializer_list<int>`. When it's used as an argument, [special rules for overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization) will be applied for overloaded function call.

(emphasis mine)

> - Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class and the initializer list **has one element**, the implicit conversion sequence is the one required **to convert the element to the parameter type**

`{42}` has only one element with type `int`, then it's exact match for the overload `void f(int)`. While for `void f(std::vector<int>)` a user-defined conversion is needed. So `void f(int)` will be picked up here.

> Is there any way of forcing the compiler to pick the `std::vector` overload (without explicitly constructing `std::vector<int>{42})` even on 1-element lists?

As a wordaround, you can put additional braces to force the compiler construct a `std::initializer_list<int>` and then pick up `void f(std::vector<int>)`:

```
f({{42}});
```

[LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2041f9b553bc8e75)

Answer (score 1):

**Forcing std::vector overload**

```
int main()
{
    f(std::vector<int>{42}); // the vector overload is being picked up now
}
```

**Why isn't the `vector(initializer_list)` constructor being picked up?**

Assume that another header declares a `void f(std::set<int> v)`.

How would you like the compiler to react when faced with `f({1})`: construct a `vector` or construct a `set`?

Comment: Damn, I forgot to mention without a cast, edited the question... Yes, this works indeed but looks clumsy. But probably that's the only way, as `{2}` seems to be treated like an int.

Comment: @vsoftco nit-picking: that's not a cast, that's object of the explicit type being constructed in place. Being precise comes with the risk of being more verbose, even in real life.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, I modified the question.

Comment: @vsoftco likewise, I adjusted my answer.

Comment: I will just spit out "ambiguous call" error. Is there any rule that says `{n}` is an `int` and not an initializer list?

Comment: @vsoftco So, you admit that's an "error of ambiguity" that needs to be signalled, and we are quibbling now over how the error message should read?

Comment: The problem is that `{42}` is not treated like a list, but like an `int`, and I don't understand why. And yes, had it been treated like a list, then of course I agree it would be an ambiguity. And more strange, when you add an `std::initializer_list<int>` overload, that one will trump and will gladly accept `{42}` as an init-list.

Comment: @vsoftco "And more strange, when you add an std::initializer_list<int> overload, that one will trump and will gladly accept {42} as an init-list" What exactly is so strange in that? It's a perfect match with no ambiguity!

Comment: @vsoftco "The problem is that {42} is not treated like a list, but like an int, and I don't understand why." I don't know either (I'm not a language lawyer), but I can see that, without a `std::initializer_list<int>` overload, your formulation is ambiguous.